# Retrieving data information from another table Left Join SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join

User A liked User C Post

Table **Users**:

```
id_user name
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
```

Table **Posts**:

```
 id_post    post            user_post
   15       hi                  2
   19       how are you         3
   23       hello               2
```

Table **likes**:

```
   id_like  id_liker liked_post_id  liked_user_id
   45           1           19          3
```

From `table likes` I show results

User 1 liked post 19 that belongs to user 3

```
SELECT liked_user_id,_liker,liked_post_id 
FROM likes
WHERE liked_user_id = 3
```

How do I show the next

User A liked User C Post which is "How are you"

I tried but I get an error:

```
 SELECT name
 FROM users as u
 LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT id_post, post, user_post
      FROM posts as p
      LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT liked_user_id, id_liker, liked_post_id 
           FROM likes 
           WHERE liked_user_id = 3
          ) AS b ON u.id_post = b.liked_post_id
     ) AS c ON u.id_user = c.user_post
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: the number of results doesnt match, with bigger tables, it shows more results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.`name`, v.`name`, p.post  
FROM likes 
LEFT JOIN Users as u on likes.id_liker=u.id_user
LEFT JOIN Users as v on likes.liked_user_id=v.id_user
LEFT JOIN Posts as p on likes.liked_post_id=p.id_post
WHERE likes.liked_user_id=3
```

Comment: where do you use `liked_user_id=3`

Comment: What's your likes.liked_user_id's type? Note the difference between varchar and int. If type is varchar, use WHERE likes.liked_user_id='3' instead.

Comment: my bad. It worked perfectly after a few tries. thank you!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT liker.name AS liker_name
    ,liked.name AS liked_name
    ,p.post
FROM likes AS l
LEFT JOIN Users AS liker ON liker.id_user = l.id_liker
LEFT JOIN Users AS liked ON liked.id_user = l.liked_user_id
LEFT JOIN Posts AS p ON p.id_post = l.liked_post_id
    AND l.liked_user_id = p.user_post 
 WHERE l.liked_user_id = 3
```

Comment: where does `liker` and `liked` comes from...are they new tables? trying with this code, it retieves error. When do you use `3` in your code?

Comment: ok you need it for the user id 3 only... Will update the solution

Comment: liker  & liked are only the table alias name

Comment: @Jean, I have edited the solution. Please check. Let me know if any error comes

Comment: @Jean Oh... it was a syntax error as I have used AS in palce of ON... Corrected it.. Check the new answer